# Correct way to emit value with Marko.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, marko

I want a Marko.js component to emit an event along with a value, I then want the containing component to listen for the event and access the value.

I have a simple button component which looks like this:

```js
class {
    doSomething() {
        this.emit('buttonClicked', {someValue:'10'});
    }
}

<button.example-button on-click('doSomething')>Click me!</button>
```

The containing component then looks like this...

```js
class {
 onButtonClicked(data){
  console.log("I heard event:" + data.someValue);
 }
}

<div class="button-manager">
  <my-button on-buttonClicked('onButtonClicked') />
</div>
```

This works and correctly logs the event with the value. However I am a little confused as I would expect the syntax in the container to reference the passed arguments in the event listener... like this...

```js
<div class="button-manager">
  <my-button on-buttonClicked('onButtonClicked', data) />
</div>
```

However that then traces out an empty object. If I put a string as the argument that string is logged and overwrites the original data argument passed through from the emitter.

Is this the intended behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Given the following and continuing with your example:

```
class {
    onButtonClicked(foo, bar, eventArg){
        console.log('foo:', foo);
        console.log('bar:', bar);
        console.log('eventArg:', eventArg);
    }
}

$ var foo = 'foo';
$ var bar = 'bar';

<div class="button-manager">
    <my-button on-buttonClicked('onButtonClicked', foo, bar) />
</div>
```

The output will be the following on `buttonClicked` is emitted:

```
foo: foo
bar: bar
eventArg: { someValue: 10 }
```

Additional arguments passed after the method name for an event handler will be passed to event handler method at the beginning of the arguments. See: http://markojs.com/docs/components/#codeon-eventmethodname-argscode

Side note: this was intended to mirror the behavior of [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions)

Unless there was additional data that you wanted to pass to your event handler method (data that was not provided when `this.emit()` was called) then there is no need to bind any additional arguments.

Hope that answers your question.